# How do i snap a copied part of a mesh to the parent of the mesh, wiht a distance created by edge?

Tags: modeling, transforms

Basically I want to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> some faces/parts of a mesh, then copy paste it next to the mesh I duplicated, create a small line (edge) between the meshes (of the same mesh?) and finally snap the duplicated mesh vertex to the created empty end of the line edge, so it looks like this:

Corresponding vertex --- Edge --- Corresponding vertex from the duplicated mesh

Basically i want to copy paste(<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) a part of a mesh, then move the mesh so bottom verticle snaps(and copied mesh moves, not only the verticle) to one point(unused verticle) a line(edge) i have created.

This is a better picture to explain what i exactly need.

Selected mesh bottom verticle to the empty/unused end of the edge(snapping to the edge verticle, whitout distorting the model(so no (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) merge) circled in red in the picture below.

[image]

This is what i mean:

[image: picture1]
[image: picture2]

So after some mesh joining and scaling, end result would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to manually do what Solidify modifier does? It could have some problems e.g. in the corners but that depends on the case

Comment: Yeah, i want to do this,ill try it out later(i found a problem i have to fix before i can use solidify modifier....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is enable **Snapping**.

After you have duplicated your mesh:

1: At the bottom of the 3D window enable the **Snapping** tool. Then click on the icon to the right of that and choose the the element to snapt to, in this case choose **Vertex**. To the right of that is some **snap target** options, choose **Active**.

2: With everything deselected, right mouse select the vertex on the duplicated mesh that you want to be able to snap to any other vertex. 
This vertex will be the **Active** vertex. (it is highlighted in red in the gif below). Now select the rest of the duplicated mesh by hovering your mouse over part of it and hit the **L** key.

3: **G** key to move the duplicated mesh about and you will find that the **Active** vertex of the duplicate will snap to the other vertices.

Don't forget to disable the snapping tool whnen you have finished with it .

Something you may not be aware of is that a mesh face only has one side. You can see this if you enable **Backface culling** from the **Properties panel**.

You should now be able to see that the duplicated mesh has its faces facing the wrong way. Facing inwards! this will create shading problems later on so you need to **Flip** the faces so that they will be on the outside when you join the edges of both meshes.

To do this: With only the duplicate mesh selected, open the **Tools panel** on the right and then open the **Shading tab**. From the **Normals** menu choose the **Flip Direction** option.

To join the edges of the original and duplicated mesh: In **Edge select mode** select the outer edges of both meshes then hit the **W** key to open the **Specials** menu. From there choose the **Bridge Edge Loops** option. **

[image]